# Are MAC addresses required to be globally unique? If so why?

Tags: mac-address

I am unable to understand the necessity of having a globally unique MAC address on a network card. Since TCP/IP protocol suite uses MAC address for machine identification only within the network, in my view MAC should be unique locally and not globally.

I will be grateful for explanation of requirement of MAC being unique globally.

Comment: And how would you ensure the addresses are unique locally?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In that case I presume there is no other technical reason except that to ensure MAC to be locally unique, it is made globally unique.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that is the only reason, however some network drivers allow the MAC to be manually reassigned!